# Сколько памяти занимает хранение указателя?

Tags: c++, указатели

Как узнать, сколько памяти занимает хранение указателя?

Comment: `sizeof` почему-то не сработал?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Размер указателя зависит от разрядности вашего приложения:

- на 32-битной версии - 4 байта
- на 64-битной версии - 8 байт

---

А вообще, вы всегда можете узнать его размер посредством функции `sizeof`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int* x = new int(1);
    std::cout << sizeof(x) << std::endl;
}
```

---

**Update:**
В общем случае, размер указателя в C++ может зависеть от архитектуры используемой платформы, т.к. в стандарте плюсов этот момент явно не прописан, т.е. данная особенность, как и многие другие, является unspecified/implementation defined behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Есть переносимый способ узнать это, просто написать, например

```
std::cout << sizeof(void*);
```

при компиляции программы подставиться константа.
Все указатели (`void*`, `int*`, `struct SomeStruct *`) обычно имеют одинаковый размер.

Comment: Ээээ... Не все указатели обязаны быть одинакового размера. Например, указатели на код и на данные на многих архитектурах имеют разную длину.

Comment: @VladD, указатели будут одного размера, если не говорить об указателях на функции-члены, и на члены класса.

Comment: @VladD, хотя это опять только исходя из моего опыта. Судя по стандарту, никаких гарантий нет. Можно получить лишь максимальный размер указателя, а размер всех указателей нельзя. Так что оба ответа неверны, в общем случае.

Comment: @ixSci: Это вас flat-модель памяти разбаловала :) А помните DOS с её compact, large, tiny и другими моделями?

Comment: @VladD, помню в плане изучения, работать с ней приходилось только на лабах. Вообще, конечно, вопросы по C++ это всегда очень забавно,  потому что корректного ответа очень часто дать нельзя, ибо очень много unspecified, implementation defined и прочее.

Comment: В Linux совпадает с размером `long`.

Comment: @ixSci: Там можно было сказать, например, что код влезет в один сегмент (64К), и тогда все указатели на код делались короткими. Вообще там была забавная модель памяти: например, указатели 0x0000:0x1000 и 0x0100:0x0000 указывали в одно и то же место (хотя были бинарно разные).

Comment: @avp: Мне казалось, это специфика интеловской платформы, разве нет?

Comment: @VladD, может и так, но помнится где-то читал, что это должно быть для всех.