# Длина адреса переменной (указателя)

Tags: c++, указатели

```
short int a;
short int *pa;
pa = &a;
*pa = 10;
cout << "a  = " << a << endl; //a  = 10
cout.setf(ios::hex);
cout << "&a = " << &a;        //&a = 0x7ffc079b67ae
```

Неужели `short int` хватает чтобы записать такой длинный адрес переменной? Насколько мне известно, адреса должны выглядеть примерно так `0x7ffc079b67ae`. Неужели `short int` хватает чтобы записать такой адрес, или запись адреса в указатель происходит каким-то другим образом? Объясните, пожалуйста, кто разбирается. Или это происходит как-то по какой-то ссылке на указатель?

Comment: Где вы тут увидели запись адреса в `short int`? Ничего подобного в коде нет. Адрес у вас записывается в указатель `short int *`, а не в `short int`. Уточняйте вопрос.

Comment: [размер указателя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500450/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)

_Размер указателя зависит от разрядности вашего приложения:

на 32-битной версии - 4 байта
на 64-битной версии - 8 байт_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проведем аналогию - адрес на конверте в общем-то, всегда одного размера, указываете ли вы на небоскреб или на собачью будку :) Т.е. размер указателя не связан с размером того, на что он указывает.

А чтобы понять, какого конкретно размера ваш указатель, добавьте в программу следующие строки:

```
cout << "Размер a  = " << sizeof(a)  << " байт\n";
cout << "Размер pa = " << sizeof(pa) << " байт\n";
```

и посмотрите, что они выведут.